# How to make post request in axios with form data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native emulator on frontend and backend is node server. In node server I am using `app.use(cors())`. In POSTMAN it is working see screenshot but on frontend not working why so?

Code:

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();
      bodyFormData.append('photo', {
        uri: this.state.filePath,
        name:this.state.filename,
        type:this.state.filetype
      })

      console.log("bodyformdata: ", bodyFormData)
      axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/uploads',
          data: bodyFormData,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
          })
          .then(function (response) {
              //handle success
              console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              //handle error
              console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)))
          });
```

Above code gives network error but in postman it works fine why so?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]